# are extern variables initialized to their default value?

Tags: c++, extern

I know that if a char array is a global or a static local, its elements get initialized to \0's, but what if the char array is an extern variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the variable was declared as extern but is nonglobal, it too receives the same initialization handling. For instance

```
namespace A { extern int x; int x;}
```

This nonglobal variable will be initialized to zero. All namespace scope variables receive this handling.

Answer (score 3):

`extern` is only a ***declaration***.
Whether the variable will be initialized depends on the ***definition***.

Also, the value of the variable will depend on type of initialization. The C++ standard defines 3 types of initialization:

- Zero-initialize
- Default-Initialize
- Value-Initialize

C++03 Standard 8.5/5 aptly defines each.

**Good Read:**

[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declarationn)

Comment: a variable declared as extern always will be initialized.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, and the value will depend on the type of initiazation

Comment: your anwswer indicates otherwise because you made your "yes it will be" dependent on whether it is global. what was your intent?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub that's because the variable must exist for linkage, not because it's extern

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: uhm...You are correct on second read it seemed tangential. Modified it.

Answer (score 3):

An extern variable is just a declaration. The variable is initialized in the module that defined it. Since in that module the variable is a global, it gets zero-initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The `extern` keyword only declares that the variable exists, it does not define its value.
because of global scope it initialised to 0